# How to fix 'Int' is not convertible to 'String' in a comparison that uses only Int?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, type-conversion

Imagine my surprise that this Swift code generates an error in Xcode 6.1.1:

```
public func unlockNextLevel() -> Int
{
    var highest : Int = 123
    return (highest < highestUnlockedLevel)
}
```

More precisely, it tells me that in the return line:

> 'Int' is not convertible to 'String'

So, since I had some of these weird conversion errors before, I thought I'll try converting both types to Int and see what I get:

```
public func unlockNextLevel() -> Int
{
    var highest : Int = 123
    return (Int(highest) < Int(highestUnlockedLevel))
}
```

I then get the following error on the return line:

> Could not find an overload for '<' that accepts the supplied arguments

But when I break it down to just constant values:

```
return (Int(3) < Int(12))
```

I get the *int not convertible to string* error again.

> 'Int' is not convertible to 'String'

Gnnnnn.... oh-kay, so I give it another shot without the brackets:

```
return highest < highestUnlockedLevel
```

This then gives me yet another error message:

> Cannot invoke '<' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue Int, @lvalue Int)'

Okay, I get it Swift, I'm stoopid. Or maybe ... hmmm, take this, Swift:

```
var result = highest < highestUnlockedLevel
return result
```

Arrrr ... nope. Swift decides that now the return line constitutes yet another error:

> 'Bool' is not convertible to 'Int'

(... dials number for psych evaluation ...)

---

So ... could someone explain to me:

- how to fix or work around this issue?
- and of course: *Why?? Oh, why???*

**Note:** This is in a mixed Objc/Swift project if that makes any difference. The `highestUnlockedLevel` variable is declared in a Swift class with custom setter and getter.

Comment: `'Bool' is not convertible to 'Int'` actually describes the problem clearly :)

Comment: dammit ... I'm blind :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(highest < highestUnlockedLevel)` produces `Bool` not `Int` (unlike Objective-C where it returns `int` that can be automatically converted to `BOOL`), thats why you get the error. But certainly its wrong and misleading error as the problem is that `Bool` cannot be converted to `Int`.

Comment: I realized that just now. Thanks :)